# Implementing timeouts for node.js callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

This is a typical situation in node.js:

```
asyncFunction(arguments, callback);
```

When `asynFunction` completes, `callback` gets called. A problem I see with this pattern is that, if `asyncFunction` *never* completes (and `asynFunction` doesn't have a built-in time-out system) then `callback` will never be called. Worse, it seems that `callback` has no way of determining that `asynFunction` will never return.

I want to implement a "timeout" whereby if `callback` has not been called by `asyncFunction` within 1 second, then `callback` automatically gets called with the assumption that `asynFunction` has errored out. What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: The standard way is that `callback` *always* gets called.

Comment: How can you guaranty that? Say a server dies...

Comment: @Randomblue: The other server only comunicates w/ your code and is *not* resonsible for calling your callbacks directly. `asyncFunction`, and the part that actually calls `callback` are all on your side of the fence so it is reasonably expected that it should do this kind of error handling for you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not familiar with any libraries that do this, but it's not hard to wire up yourself.

```
// Setup the timeout handler
var timeoutProtect = setTimeout(function() {

  // Clear the local timer variable, indicating the timeout has been triggered.
  timeoutProtect = null;

  // Execute the callback with an error argument.
  callback({error:'async timed out'});

}, 5000);

// Call the async function
asyncFunction(arguments, function() {

  // Proceed only if the timeout handler has not yet fired.
  if (timeoutProtect) {

    // Clear the scheduled timeout handler
    clearTimeout(timeoutProtect);

    // Run the real callback.
    callback();
  }
});
```

Comment: This calls callback twice if asyncFunction succeeds after 5000ms.

Comment: @herby yeah just fixed that :)

Comment: Calls callback without parameters (but well, since this is ad-hoc, they can be added case by case).

Comment: Race conditions can arise if timeoutProtect = null; is not executed before the "if" evaluation.

Comment: it doesn't handle endless cycle in async function

Answer (score 8):

You probably need to come out with a solution of your own. Like

```
function callBackWithATimeout (callback, timeout) {
  var run, timer;
  run = function () {
    if (timer) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
      callback.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
  timer = setTimeout(run, timeout, "timeout");
  return run;
}
```

and then

```
asyncFunction(arguments, callBackWithATimeout(callback, 2000));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
function ensureExecution(func, timeout) {
    var timer, run, called = false;

    run = function() {   
        if(!called) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            called = true;
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        }   
    };

    timer = setTimeout(run, timeout);
    return run;
}
```

Usage:

```
asyncFunction(arguments, ensureExecution(callback, 1000));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/DU6DQ/)

But note the following:

- The timeout is started immediately when you call `ensureExecution`, so you cannot cache that function reference.
- The arguments passed to the callback will differ. For example `asyncFunction` might pass some arguments to `callback` upon success, but if the function is called by the timeout, no arguments will be passed. You have to keep that it mind. You could also provide default arguments with which the function should be called in this case:

  ```
  function ensureExecution(func, timeout, args, this_obj) {
      // ...
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
          run.apply(this_obj, args);
      }, timeout);
      //...
  }
  ```

Comment: This calls callback twice if asyncFunction succeeds after timeout.

Comment: Calls `func` without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem with a content script trying to open the port on the BG extension before the BG extension was ready.  A work around was to wait for the BG extension to reply to a message and repeat this till successful.  Here are the code snippets.

**Content Script:**

```
var nTimes     = 10;
var bIsReady = false;
checkBGReady();
function checkBGReady() {
  if (!bIsReady) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msgText: "hello "+nTimes}, function(response) {
      if (response && response.ack) {
        console.log("have response:"+response.ack+" "+nTimes);
        bIsReady = true;
        // continue with initialization
        bootStrap(sURL);
        checkReady();
      } else {
        console.log("have no ack response %o",response);
      }
    });
  }
  nTimes -= 1;
  if (nTimes > 0 && !bIsReady) {
    setTimeout(checkBGReady,100);
  }
}
```

**BG Extension**

```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?"from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :"from the extension");
    if (request.msgText) {
      console.log("Have msg "+request.msgText);
       sendResponse({ack: "have contact "+request.msgText});
    }
  });
```

In my case it usually took after the first 100ms delay.