# Node.js killing an async call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Is there any way in Node.js to kill an async operation and preventing it from completing (calling callbacks, or resolving promise) ?

To be more specific, let's say I did an `http.get()` call. It is an async operation that eventually will call the callback passed, or fire an error event. But it takes too long and the logic in my code could say "hey, I have been waiting for so long, I don't want to wait any longer!" and do something else instead. The problem is, the callback will eventually be called, and that might mess up stuff! So yeah, is there a way to stop that callback from being executed? My idea was:

```
var notWaitingAnyMore = false;
http.get({}, function(res) {
    if(notWaitingAnyMore) { // do stuff! }
});
//do some other stuff
//now fed up with waiting:
notWaitingAnyMore = true;
```

But this doesn't seem like a nice solution to me...

Comment: Make this use promises. Then, shove in an intermediate promise that also completes when notWaitingAnyMore becomes true and throws away the http result.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/8377810/57095 ?

Comment: Do you want to set a [timeout on an `http` call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node)? It's worth noting that many JavaScript Promise libraries support native timeouts that handle this for you automatically.

Comment: No, http.get() is an example, it could be a DB call, or any async operation for that matter

Comment: This is possible only if the API provides a mechanism for it (like `clearTimeout` does for `setTimeout`). Otherwise, you'll simply need to have your callback aware of the possibility that it may need to do nothing, as you've shown in your example. I think Promises are probably an idiomatic way to do this, as others have already suggested.

Comment: Your question implies that you're setting `notWaitingAnyMore` to `true` synchronously.  Is that true?  If so, your calls will always time out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use promises.  For example, if you are using `bluebird`, this problem is very easily solved:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  http.get({}, resolve);
}).timeout(500) // timeout length in ms
.then(function(res) {
  // do stuff!
}).catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function(err) {
  // do you need to do something after it times out?
})
//do some other stuff
```

Comment: bluebird sounds nice, I will check it out, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're super close

```
function outerMethod(input, callback){
  var notWaitingAnyMore = false;
  var maxTimeout = 1000*60; // 1min
  http.get({}, function(res) {
    if(!notWaitingAnyMore) {
      // do stuff!
      notWaitingAnyMore = true;
      callback(null, res);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    // We want to avoid calling back a second time if the http callback ran first:
    if(!notWaitingAnyMore) {
      notWaitingAnyMore = true;
      callback('timeout');
    } else {
      return
    }
  }, maxTimeout)
};
```