# How long can await wait in an async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I wanted to know , how long will await wait [and hence keeps every resource in RAM] in an async function.
Consider this example:

```js
async function my_func(some_big_sized_data){
 let db_input = await gettingDBinputWhichIsDamnedSlow();
//then do some processing based on db_input and some_big_sized_data
}
```

Now what if DB keeps taking forever in replying.
How long will await function wait and hold all those data [and hold up RAM in the process]?
Is there a timeout of await too , or await can wait pratically infinitely ? [how to control this timeout time]

Comment: Basically, forever.

Comment: Also the `await` doesn't hold up anything.

Comment: Check this link too. Might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587789/how-to-set-a-time-limit-to-run-asynchronous-function-in-node-js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`await` is practically a syntax sugar to consume promise. And promise can stuck pending forever, so does await. There's no builtin timeout mechanism for async/await.

Example:

```
async function foo() {
  await new Promise(r => r);
  console.log('complete');
}
```

If you run this foo function, that await is never gonna resolve, so it never reaches `console.log('complete')`.

But `await` per se doesn't hold up RAM. Whether some resources stay in RAM or got GC'ed is determined by reference count, such mechanism is not related to `await`.

I said there's no builtin timeout mechanism for async/await. However, since it's just syntax sugar for promise, you can wrap your `gettingDBinputWhichIsDamnedSlow` promise within another promise to create ad hoc timeout control manually.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error('timeout')) 
  }, 10000) // wait 10 sec

  gettingDBinputWhichIsDamnedSlow().then(value => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    resolve(value)
  })
})
```

Comment: Regarding the first example, while `count` indeed can't be GCed because of the setInterval callback, both Promises can be, nothing holds any reference to it.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way you can have a timeout for `await`, it would block as long as the Promise takes to get settled.

You can write your own function to get the timeout behavior, by simply using the `Promise.race` API.

The `Promise.race` from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race):

> The Promise.race() method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects
>   as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects,
>   with the value or reason from that promise.

```js
function gettingDBinputWhichIsDamnedSlow() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(res, 5000, "data from db"));
}

//takes timeout in ms
function awaitWithTimeout(timeout, ...args) {
  function timeOut() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => setTimeout(rej, timeout, new Error(`Timed out after ${timeout}ms`)));
  }
  return Promise.race([...args, timeOut()]);
}

async function my_func(some_big_sized_data) {
  let db_input = null;
  try {
    db_input = await awaitWithTimeout(1000, gettingDBinputWhichIsDamnedSlow());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
  console.log("db_input", db_input);
}

my_func();
```