# If EventEmitter is gotten an async callback, is there likelihood that a returned promise would be garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As it follows from the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous), Node.js `EventEmitter` calls its listeneres synchronously.

```
const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('event', async (e) => {
  await sendData(e);
  updateUI();
});
```

Considering this code, one can make a reasonable guess of whenever `sendData()` be overly delayed, a promise returned from the async callback may be collected, so `updateUI()` will never get executed. Does this guess has any ground?

There is also currently experimental [capture rejections of promises](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_capture_rejections_of_promises) api which enables to receive notifications of promises rejections (through `error` event). Does it mean in this case an `EventEmitter` instance keeps all promises references in the memory, therefore collecting is impossible?

Answer (score 0):

> *"Node.js `EventEmitter` calls its listeneres synchronously."*

Sure, but that does not mean the contents of said listeners can't be async.

Since that assertion is false, logically, await will [wait indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61220406/1835379).