# Event listening timeout - node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, dom-events

I'm trying to make a simple exchange between my node app and an UDP server. I'm calling a tracker server of the bittorrent network to be precise.

I need an event listner that, if it catch the 'message' event in a certain timeframe runs one callback function and stop listening but if it gets to the end of that timeframe it would run an other callback function and stop listening.

I feel like the solution lies somewhere close to `Promise`s but I have trouble finding how to do that.

Or maybe there is a function that I haven't seen in the `dgram` library. The `net` package has `socket.setTimeout(timeout[, callback])` but `dgram` seem not to have anything like it.

Comment: Is it something you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/8377810/980828?

Answer (score -1):

> Is it something you're looking for stackoverflow.com/a/8377810/980828? – [LEQADA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980828/leqada)?

Yep!